# Setting up automatic daily backup of a database in SQL Server Express 2017?

Tags: sql-server-express

I am currently running SQL Server Express 2017, and I have a daily backup that is exporting a .ZIP file that only contains the .BAK file of the entire database every night at 3 a.m. It is working just fine.

My question is, where is this being done? It is Express so there are no maintenance plans, and I checked the Windows Task Scheduler and there are no nightly jobs running to create the backup.

Does anyone know of other ways this could be accomplished?

Comment: SQL Server Agent?

Comment: I don't think SQL Server Agent can run with any of the Express versions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. There is a third party software running on my machine that performs the daily backup.